# Excel Macros Changing trigger action and insert copied values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a worksheet that tracks the hiring process. On one sheet (Tracking), I have each subject assigned to a row, and as the process advances, the user updates the row to reflect recent progress. I am trying to record the history on a second sheet (Documentation). This will hold a record of all steps taken towards each application.

I currently have two macros. 1 to copy all of the Tracker sheet and insert them into the Documentation sheet (not paste because I don't want to overwrite past history. I then have my second macro on my Documentation sheet that removes duplicates, as the user often only updates a couple rows, and I don't need all of the data from the tracker. I have put the macro code below.

Tracker Sheet (the copy and insert code)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Worksheets("Tracker").Range("A3:S100").Copy
    Worksheets("Documentation").Range("A2").Insert xlShiftDown

End Sub
```

Documentation sheet (the remove duplicates)

```
Sub sbRemoveDuplicates()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:S100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 15), 
    Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

I have the array as 2 and 15 because these are the two unique columns that I want to base the duplicates off of.

What I am trying to do is:

1. On the tracker sheet, have it only insert values (there are lots of functions)
2. Have the remove duplicates function automatically occur after the values are inserted
3. Have all of this run either right when the workbook is opened, or some sort of trigger for right before the user would close it

I would like to have this all run in one large macro if possible, and be automated. I don't want to trust the user to manually run macro. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement: **VBE** > **ThisWorkbook** > **Paste code**.

I also made your copy range and paste range dynamic (it will copy data from row 3 down to last available row, and paste data (values only) on `Documentation` on the first available blank row)

As is, this will run before the workbook is closed. If you want to trigger this when the workbook opens, enclose the code (except top and bottom line) inside:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Code here
End Sub
```

To Implement on close:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim TLRow As Long, DLRow As Long

TLRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker").Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DLRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Documentation").Range("A" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Documentation").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Thisworkbook.Sheets("Tracker").Range("A3:S" & TLRow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Documentation").Range("A" & DLRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Thisworkbook.Sheets("Documentation").Range("A2:S" & DLRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 15), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Alternatively, rather than putting the code in one (or the other) event procedures, put it in a normal `Sub`, and just *call* it from the event procedure. IDK if there's a best-practice for this, but I try to minimize the code that exists in the event handlers, and abstract that away to other subs/function calls.

Comment: I would personally put this on a button and not use any event. Either way, once you add data, you will have to either close or open the book to see the finished result which doesn't seem ideal. The possibilities are *endless* :0

Comment: I'd make the same case for a button: put the actual, executable code in a `Sub` and call it from the button's `Click` handler :D

Comment: I will look into a button! I am just worried that as soon as one user forgets to press the button and exits the workbook that the history will no longer be accurate. Is there a way to force the user to press the button, i.e. a warning before close that mentions the button?

Comment: It works fantastically now, exactly as imagined. Thank you so much for the help!